# Style name in tikz called from macro/variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expl3

Here is my issue : I am trying to write a bit of code that will draw a node in a given style.
The styles are defined in a separate file.
The name of the style is defined by a function that will create several variables with the same root name and a roman number to distinguish them.
This is the design and it cannot be changed.

I would like to access the name of the style via a function called xaller that retrieve the content of the variable 'root+roman number' : it's working fine when the content is used to be displayed but not when the content is supposed to be used as the name of a style.
I guess I need to indicate that the content retrieved designate a style for tikz, but I don't see how I could do that.

In the MWE, you will find a switch to what is currently working and what is not : I can access the content of the variable and use it as a style name when accessing the variable directly , but I can't use it when accessing via the xaller function.
I tried a workaround with the function SetStyle which is supposed to attribute the name of the style to \monStyle , but it also doesn't work.

Any pointer would be helpful.
Sorry if the code seems overkill, I minimized it the best I could.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
% graphics and color
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, patterns, fit, positioning}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}


%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================
% Define the xpl3 functions to attributes the variables
%\include{fonctionsMWE}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \SetStyle #1
  { 
% clear new car si new seulement, se plaint que la variable existe deja
\tl_clear_new:N \l_my_tl

% convertit l argument en chiffre romain
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { \int_to_Roman:n {#1} }

% concatene variableCouleurMatrice a ma var \l_my_tl par la gauche
\tl_put_left:Nn \l_my_tl { variableStyle  }

%show la variable
%\tl_use:N \l_my_tl
% use permet d executer la variable
\use:c { \tl_use:N \l_my_tl }
\let\monStyle\use:c { \tl_use:N \l_my_tl }
%\let\monStyle\variableStyleII
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Automation trial 7  : utilise la syntaxe expl3

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefinitionVariablesEnIndividuel}{O{variable}}
 {% pass control to an inner function
  % #1 is the "name part", default "variable"
  \aline_df:n { #1 }
 }

% define an integer variable
\int_new:N \l_aline_df_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aline_df:n
 {
  % the integer variable assigns the trailing roman number
  \int_zero:N \l_aline_df_int
  % start the recursion
  \__aline_df_peek:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aline_df_peek:n
 {
  % check whether the next token is { (ignoring spaces)
  \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NT \c_group_begin_token
   {
    % if it is, increment the counter and call
    % \__aline_df_next:nn { #1 } { #2 }, where
    % { #2 } is the next braced group
    \int_incr:N \l_aline_df_int
    \__aline_df_next:nn { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aline_df_next:nn
 {
  % if the variable is already defined, clear it
  % otherwise create it
  \tl_clear_new:c { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int } }
  \tl_clear_new:c { #1 ConstanteLongueur }
  % set the variable
  \tl_set:cn { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int }}  { #2 }
  \tl_set:cx { #1 ConstanteLongueur } { \int_eval:n  { \l_aline_df_int } }

  % restart the recursion
  \__aline_df_peek:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff



%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================

%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================
%\include{stylesMWE}
\tikzstyle{teteColonneNegatif} = [
    text centered,
    text=white, font=\bfseries,
    minimum height=1em,
    text depth=0.5em, text height=1em, 
    text width = 3cm,
    rectangle, fill=none, draw=none, rounded corners,
    fill=black!100
    ]
\tikzset{
    teteColonne/.style={
    text centered,
    text=white, font=\bfseries,
    minimum height=1em,
    text depth=0.5em, text height=1em, 
    text width = 5cm,
    rectangle, fill=none, draw=none, rounded corners,
    fill=red!100
    },
    teteColonne/.default=white
}


\newcommand{\xaller}[2]{%
      \uppercase\expandafter
     {\expandafter\def\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\romannumeral #1}}%
      \csname #2\tmp\endcsname%
      %\csname variableStyle\tmp\endcsname%
}


%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================
% Define all the variables variableStyleN
\DefinitionVariablesEnIndividuel[variableStyle]{teteColonne}{teteColonneNegatif}{teteColonneNegatif}{teteColonne}{teteColonne}{teteColonne}{teteColonneNegatif}{teteColonne}

%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================

Wether the code is called from the variable or via the call of xaller, it is the same result :

xaller call : \xaller{1}{variableStyle}

direct variable : \variableStyleI

=======================================================


% Code to switch between what works (Generalization at false) and what doesn't (Generalization at true) 
\newif\ifGeneralization
\Generalizationtrue
\Generalizationfalse


% Use monStyle as a tmp variable for the node 
\ifGeneralization
    \let\monStyle\xaller{1}{variableStyle}
    %\SetStyle{1}
\else
    \let\monStyle\variableStyleI
\fi

Style used : \monStyle
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}%
%\node[\variableStyleI](nom) at (1,10){\variableStyleI};
\node[\monStyle](nom) at (1,10){\monStyle};
\end{tikzpicture}


% Use monStyle as a tmp variable for the node 
\ifGeneralization
    \let\monStyle\xaller{2}{variableStyle}
\else
    \let\monStyle\variableStyleII
\fi
\let\monStyle\variableStyleII


Style used : \monStyle
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}%
%\node[\variableStyleII](nom) at (1,10){\variableStyleII};
\node[\monStyle](nom) at (1,10){\monStyle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: It looks like your `\xaller` is not expandable, check `\xdef\monStyle{\xaller{1}{variableStyle}}`. Probably some texpert will tell you why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `\xaller` to be used here, it has to be expandable.
So it can use neither `\def` nor `\uppercase`.

To make an expandable version (which is also more readable IMO), you can use expl3:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \xaller #1 #2 {
  \use:c { #2 \int_to_Roman:n { #1 } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The second problem is your usage of `\let`:
The line

```
\let\monStyle\xaller{2}{variableStyle}
```

makes `\monStyle` an alias for `\xaller`, but `\xaller` is not expanded and `{2}{variableStyle}` are just output as regular text to the document.
Later, when `\monStyle` is used, TeX tries to read the `\xaller` arguments and misses the number. This can be fixed by expanding `\xaller` three times (this needs a lot of `\expandafter`s) or by by using `\def` instead:

```
\def\monStyle{\xaller{2}{variableStyle}}
```

This results in the working version

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
% graphics and color
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, patterns, fit, positioning}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}


%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================
% Define the xpl3 functions to attributes the variables
%\include{fonctionsMWE}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \SetStyle #1
  { 
% clear new car si new seulement, se plaint que la variable existe deja
\tl_clear_new:N \l_my_tl

% convertit l argument en chiffre romain
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { \int_to_Roman:n {#1} }

% concatene variableCouleurMatrice a ma var \l_my_tl par la gauche
\tl_put_left:Nn \l_my_tl { variableStyle  }

%show la variable
%\tl_use:N \l_my_tl
% use permet d executer la variable
\use:c { \tl_use:N \l_my_tl }
\let\monStyle\use:c { \tl_use:N \l_my_tl }
%\let\monStyle\variableStyleII
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Automation trial 7  : utilise la syntaxe expl3

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefinitionVariablesEnIndividuel}{O{variable}}
 {% pass control to an inner function
  % #1 is the "name part", default "variable"
  \aline_df:n { #1 }
 }

% define an integer variable
\int_new:N \l_aline_df_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aline_df:n
 {
  % the integer variable assigns the trailing roman number
  \int_zero:N \l_aline_df_int
  % start the recursion
  \__aline_df_peek:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aline_df_peek:n
 {
  % check whether the next token is { (ignoring spaces)
  \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NT \c_group_begin_token
   {
    % if it is, increment the counter and call
    % \__aline_df_next:nn { #1 } { #2 }, where
    % { #2 } is the next braced group
    \int_incr:N \l_aline_df_int
    \__aline_df_next:nn { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aline_df_next:nn
 {
  % if the variable is already defined, clear it
  % otherwise create it
  \tl_clear_new:c { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int } }
  \tl_clear_new:c { #1 ConstanteLongueur }
  % set the variable
  \tl_set:cn { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int }}  { #2 }
  \tl_set:cx { #1 ConstanteLongueur } { \int_eval:n  { \l_aline_df_int } }

  % restart the recursion
  \__aline_df_peek:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff



%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================

%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================
%\include{stylesMWE}
\tikzstyle{teteColonneNegatif} = [
    text centered,
    text=white, font=\bfseries,
    minimum height=1em,
    text depth=0.5em, text height=1em, 
    text width = 3cm,
    rectangle, fill=none, draw=none, rounded corners,
    fill=black!100
    ]
\tikzset{
    teteColonne/.style={
    text centered,
    text=white, font=\bfseries,
    minimum height=1em,
    text depth=0.5em, text height=1em, 
    text width = 5cm,
    rectangle, fill=none, draw=none, rounded corners,
    fill=red!100
    },
    teteColonne/.default=white
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \xaller #1 #2 {
  \use:c { #2 \int_to_Roman:n { #1 } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================
% Define all the variables variableStyleN
\DefinitionVariablesEnIndividuel[variableStyle]{teteColonne}{teteColonneNegatif}{teteColonneNegatif}{teteColonne}{teteColonne}{teteColonne}{teteColonneNegatif}{teteColonne}

%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================
%==================================================================================

Wether the code is called from the variable or via the call of xaller, it is the same result :

xaller call : \xaller{1}{variableStyle}

direct variable : \variableStyleI

=======================================================


% Code to switch between what works (Generalization at false) and what doesn't (Generalization at true) 
\newif\ifGeneralization
\Generalizationtrue
%\Generalizationfalse


% Use monStyle as a tmp variable for the node 
\ifGeneralization
    \def\monStyle{\xaller{1}{variableStyle}}
    %\SetStyle{1}
\else
    \let\monStyle\variableStyleI
\fi

Style used : \monStyle
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}%
%\node[\variableStyleI](nom) at (1,10){\variableStyleI};
\node[\monStyle](nom) at (1,10){\monStyle};
\end{tikzpicture}


% Use monStyle as a tmp variable for the node 
\ifGeneralization
    \def\monStyle{\xaller{2}{variableStyle}}
\else
    \let\monStyle\variableStyleII
\fi
\let\monStyle\variableStyleII


Style used : \monStyle
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}%
%\node[\variableStyleII](nom) at (1,10){\variableStyleII};
\node[\monStyle](nom) at (1,10){\monStyle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, it works perfectly !!!

Answer (score 3):

Your mix of old and new style programming is the problem, plus the misunderstanding of how `\let` works.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, patterns, fit, positioning}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xaller}{mm}
 {
  \use:c { #2 \int_to_Roman:n { #1 } }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \SetStyle { m }
 {
  \cs_set:Npx \monStyle { \xaller{#1}{variableStyle} }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\DefinitionVariablesEnIndividuel}{O{variable}}
 {% pass control to an inner function
  % #1 is the "name part", default "variable"
  \aline_df:n { #1 }
 }

% define an integer variable
\int_new:N \l_aline_df_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aline_df:n
 {
  % the integer variable assigns the trailing roman number
  \int_zero:N \l_aline_df_int
  % start the recursion
  \__aline_df_peek:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aline_df_peek:n
 {
  % check whether the next token is { (ignoring spaces)
  \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NT \c_group_begin_token
   {
    % if it is, increment the counter and call
    % \__aline_df_next:nn { #1 } { #2 }, where
    % { #2 } is the next braced group
    \int_incr:N \l_aline_df_int
    \__aline_df_next:nn { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aline_df_next:nn
 {
  % if the variable is already defined, clear it
  % otherwise create it
  \tl_clear_new:c { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int } }
  \tl_clear_new:c { #1 ConstanteLongueur }
  % set the variable
  \tl_set:cn { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int }}  { #2 }
  \tl_set:cx { #1 ConstanteLongueur } { \int_eval:n  { \l_aline_df_int } }

  % restart the recursion
  \__aline_df_peek:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzset{
  teteColonneNegatif/.style = {
    text centered,
    text=white, font=\bfseries,
    minimum height=1em,
    text depth=0.5em, text height=1em, 
    text width = 3cm,
    rectangle, fill=none, draw=none, rounded corners,
    fill=black!100
  },
  teteColonne/.style={
    text centered,
    text=white, font=\bfseries,
    minimum height=1em,
    text depth=0.5em, text height=1em, 
    text width = 5cm,
    rectangle, fill=none, draw=none, rounded corners,
    fill=red!100
  },
  teteColonne/.default=white,
}


% Define all the variables variableStyleN
\DefinitionVariablesEnIndividuel[variableStyle]
  {teteColonne}
  {teteColonneNegatif}
  {teteColonneNegatif}
  {teteColonne}
  {teteColonne}
  {teteColonne}
  {teteColonneNegatif}
  {teteColonne}

\SetStyle{1}

Style used : \verb|\monStyle|

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[\monStyle](nom) at (1,10){\monStyle};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,...,8} {
  \node[\xaller{\i}{variableStyle},text width=9cm](nom) at (1,10+\i){\xaller{\i}{variableStyle}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]